# Django pass value from JQuery UI Slider to Form

Tags: django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I was wondering how do you pass a value from a JQuery UI Slider to my Django ModelForm?

Comment: Can you please share some code or github repo, it becomes easy to help when you have code in front of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's pretty simple, just take a look on UI Slider API.
Assuming the model has a field `field_name`:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value: $('#id_field_name').val(),    // set value when updating
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#id_field_name').val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

`id_field_name` is generated automatically, so no need to define any field attributes.

Obviously you need to define your model form field as hidden, like so (unless you want to display counter as well, then skip this):

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```